# angular.js:13424 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

I'm new to programming in html/JS/AngularJS.
I'm trying to implement a simple angular component but i keep getting errors. I looked at other answers and can't find the solution why this simple implementation is creating the error in the console (the error is mentioned in title). please help.
[picture of console out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl6ZG.png)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('RingShopApp', []);
function appctrlcontroller($scope) {

}
myApp.controller('appctrl', appctrlcontroller);
console.log("appctrl done");
myApp.component('ringtabs', {
 template: "<p>sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdf</p>",
 // templateUrl: 'html/Directives/tabs.html',
 controller: myApp.controller('appctrl')
});
console.log("ringtabs component");
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
      <head>
      </head>
    
      <body  ng-app="RingShopApp">
       <ringtabs></ringtabs>
     
     
     <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js'></script>
     <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js'></script>
     <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-route.min.js'></script>
     <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js'></script>
     <script  src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js'></script>
     <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    
        
        
        
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be providing the controller function directly to your component instead of through the angular controller getter:

```
var myApp = angular.module('RingShopApp', []);
myApp.controller('appcontroller', appcontroller);
myApp.component('ringtabs', {
    template: "<p>sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdf</p>",
    controller: 'appcontroller'
});

function appcontroller($scope) {
    ...
}

appcontroller.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Be careful to add the $inject property to your controller to avoid potential problems with minification.

Answer (score 0):

@Sajeetharan posted an answer here that solved the problem but he deleted it from the comments.
His answer was that I should change ".component" to ".directive" because it was a mixture of angular2 and of angular. This is the code that was edited. It seems to work fine:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('RingShopApp', []);
function appctrlcontroller($scope) {

}
myApp.controller('appctrl', appctrlcontroller)
       
.directive('ringtabs', function(){
 return {
 templateUrl: 'html/Directives/tabs.html'
 //controller: myApp.controller('appctrl')
 }; 
});
console.log("ringtabs component");
```